# Autocomplete only when Enter is pressed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Kepler 4.3 with the [latest Grails plugin (nightly version)](http://www.springsource.org/STS-installation-instructions).

It is very unconfortable the autocomplete tool as it gets the first item when we click the <kbd>Space</kbd> key or the <kbd>.</kbd> key. For example, if we type:

```
params.property1...
```

Eclipse will actually write:

```
ParamsAction.property1...
```

How could we get the suggested item only if we press Enter?

**My solution so far is to activate the autocomplete tool only if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. It could be done here:**

- Windows - Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist > Uncheck:
  Enable auto activation

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone that might be still having this question: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist: check -Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'. This won't disable auto-activation, so you'll still get suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

As long as i know, the best solution for this would be:

- Windows - Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist > Uncheck:
  Enable auto activation